# Marginal product of capital net of depreciation

Tags: cobb-douglas

I am trying to understand how marginal product of capital net of depreciation is the following:

[image]

Given that the production function is quite standard

[image]

I understand the first term of the marginal product, but I am asking about the depreciation part.

Comment: I think there is an error in the formula. As far as I know the net MPK is simply $MP_K - \delta$. If you google "net marginal product of capital" or so you get that definition everytime. For example, in Mankiw's book [here](http://aida.econ.yale.edu/~nordhaus/homepage/documents/189-220_Mankiw7e_CH07.pdf). Your definition does not nest with the simpler case of $\delta=0$. There is an extra 1 floting around.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly why I am confused (about the extra "1"), but I don't think it is a mistake as it is from a published peer-reviewed paper.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the paper please?

Comment: Eq. (2) and (3): http://www.nber.org/papers/w13602.pdf

Comment: Notice that NBER papers are not peer-reviewed (beyond informal commentary from seminars and conferences).

Comment: Yes, included the nber link because it is mostly accessible without a login/payment. But the published version in RES (2013) uses the same equations (2) and (3)

Comment: As a further explainer, and disregarding the issue of terminology that Alecos' clarified, notice that the authors use $R$ in the Euler equation as in $C_t=RC_{t+1}$. The "true" Euler equation is $C_t=(1+r)C_{t+1}$, which is why they define $R$ with an extra 1, and where $r$ refers to the net MPK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misuse of terms.

The marginal product of capital net of depreciation is indeed $MP_k - \delta$, there is no doubt about it.

What the authors mean  is that

$$R = 1 + (MP_k - \delta)  $$

is the "gross return on capital" factor. In fact a few lines below the equation they call it exactly that, which is the correct term. Here "gross" reflects the inclusion of $1$.

Comment: Is this a common thing? Calling $1+X$ the gross return of an asset paying $X$? For instance, it the interest rate of a loan is 3%, is 1.03 the "gross" return on loans? Looks very odd to me.

Comment: @luchonacho The proper term is the "gross return _factor_" and not the "gross return rate".

Comment: That is an odd term. [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22gross+return+factor%22&client=ubuntu&hs=u3K&channel=fs&dcr=0&filter=0&biw=1920&bih=917) returns only ten results!

Comment: @luchonacho Indeed. It returns twenty thousand for "gross return on capital". The problem with this last one, is that it is sometimes used to mean $R$ as above, and sometimes is used to mean "gross interest _rate_" (i.e. prior to subtract depreciation).  Using the word "factor" helps avoid the confusion.